# Obtaining video information using FFMPEG, or possibly HTML5

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, duration

I'm making a video gallery and would like to pull some info about the video for displaying. Does anyone know how I would go about retrieving the video duration using ffmpeg? Is it possible to get this info using HTML5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use exec function in php

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/9448/how-to-get-video-duration-with-ffmpeg-and-php

Answer (score 1):

What I do (on Linux) is this:

tcprobe -i $FILE | tail -n1 | cut -d '=' -f3

tcprobe is from the transcode Debian package.

If you're on Windows there's a tool called [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en), but I haven't tried it so I can't remark on its effectiveness.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Do you know of a way to do this using ffmpeg? I'd be executing it using php, you see.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [PHPVideoToolkit](http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/downloads/detail?name=0.1.9.zip)...

> This class is a wrapper around the
>   FFmpeg, FLVTools2 and Mencoder
>   programs to allow PHP developers to
>   manipulate and convert video files in
>   any easy to use object oriented way.
>   It also currently provides FFmpeg-PHP
>   emulation in pure PHP so you wouldn't
>   need to compile and install the
>   module. Note, it isn't intended as a
>   FFmpeg-PHP replacement, only an
>   alternative solution and it is
>   recommended that if you make heavy use
>   of the FFmpeg-PHP functionality you
>   should install the module as it is
>   more efficient.
>
> PHPVideoToolkit is pretty much the
>   only video/audio class that you will
>   need from now on. It performs several
>   types of manipulation operations that
>   include video format conversion,
>   extract video frames into separate
>   image files, assemble a video stream
>   from a set of separate video images,
>   extract audio from video, watermark
>   videos and extracted frames. Several
>   parameters can also be configured like
>   the output video file format (which
>   can be Flash video or any other
>   supported by ffmpeg), video and audio
>   bit rate and sample rate, video
>   dimensions and aspect ratio. It can
>   also retrieve information about the
>   media file, such as duration, bitrate,
>   framerate, format, dimensions, display
>   aspect ratio, pixel aspect ratio,
>   audio stereo, audio frequency and
>   audio format, without any other
>   additional library such as ffmpeg-php.

- Note, I wrote it so ask any questions you want about using it.