# PHP : How check movie format is MKV or WMV

Tags: php, video

I use finfo_file and mime_content_type, it return on MKV and WMV:
application/octet-stream
PHP can't determine 2 this video format ?

If must use FFMPEG determime ( i dont know it possible or not) . then what is command to check format .

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281964/obtaining-video-information-using-ffmpeg-or-possibly-html5

Comment: try [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to read the first few bytes of the file to check if they correspond to known file signatures.

The MKV file signature, in particular, is (in hex):

```
1a 45 df a3
```

As for WMV it should be:

```
30 26 b2 75
```

See for reference:

[Extensible Binary Meta Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Binary_Meta_Language)

[Advanced Systems Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Systems_Format)

Comment: I just check 2 file mkv but first few byte is different O_O

Comment: I check 4 files see 2 code is : 1a 45 df a3 a3 42 86 81 1 42 f7 **AND** 1a 45 df a3 93 42 82 88 6d 61 74

Comment: I just got that signature from here: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html Actually, on Wikipedia it gives `1a 45 df a3` as a magic number for Matroska files, which corresponds to what you found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Binary_Meta_Language
I will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

*Using the file extension:*

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php#94279

On Apache you just have to add to entrys to the mime.types file (Apache/conf/mime.types).
Just open the file with any edito and add two lines.

```
your/mimetype      mkv
another/type       mvw
```

If you are on a shared host or do not want to mess with the server settings, you can copy the file to a location where your script can access it, and pass the path as second parameter of mime_content_type.

*Analysing the file content:*

If you have to validate if it REALLY is a mkv/mvm there is another sollution but it wont work on shared hosts:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mime-content-type.php#91646

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of magic_mime database can identify mkv/wmv files without trouble. Most like your shared host has an ancient version of the database.

You can force the use of a different database file (with the mkv/wmv definitions included) by doing:

```
$handle = finfo_open('FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE', '/path/to/updated/database/file').
```

You should be able to extract the updated database file from an Linux distro's fileinfo-type package.

Comment: where i can get database file ? but  this method dont work with 5.2 .

Comment: Any "fileinfo" package from a linux distro should do. This one is ubuntu's: http://ubuntu.media.mit.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/f/file/